# NSDate now is 1 hr off my ios emulator

Tags: iphone, nsdate, picker, nscalendar, nstimezone

Hi I am creating an NSDate which I am using to set a Picker, but when I output the picker date to NSLog it is always an hour behind the time shown in the actual picker.

Also as a test I noticed that the code:
NSDate *now = [NSDate date]; //should give me the current date and time on my emulator
NSLog(@"Date and Time now: %@", now);

The NSLog value is always 1 hour behind the time shown on my emulator.

My question is why?

Thanks in advance :)

UPDATE --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I did a couple of more tests and it turns out that NSDate using the NSGregorian Calendar was returning the correct time and then NSDate using the currentCalendar was off by 1 hour.

So my new question is why is that? I have checked the settings on my emulator and the device has its calendar set to Gregorian. Could this be due to a timezone difference? If so then is there a way for me to set the picker to use the same timezone as the users device?

Thanks

Comment: Try printing out the date using the following + (id)dateWithNaturalLanguageString:(NSString *)string locale:(id)localeDictionary and use  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation] as the localeDictionary.

Comment: Hi Ben, Thanks for your comment but I got an error saying - 

No known class method for selector 'dateWithNaturalLanguageString:'

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because your simulator time is set to default time zone (EN). NSDate is always set from your local time. When you try it on  your device it will be correct.

i have this code in my project and work fine:

```
NSDate*now = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
```

i create date and store it to my CoreData. Always that time will my actual time on my device.

Congrats to your new iPhone anyway. Welcome to big Apple Family! :)

Comment: Hi Mayo323, thanks for your comment and you are right the NSDate does return the correct time. I did a couple of more tests and it turns out that NSDate using the NSGregorian Calendar was returning the correct time and then NSDate using the currentCalendar was off by 1 hour. So my new question is why is that? I have checked the settings on my emulator and the device has its calendar set to Gregorian. How can I make my picker have the same time zone as my emulator/device?

Comment: Emulator will be always -1hr. On device will be time from your device local time zone.

Comment: Don't laugh but I don't have an iphone to test my app out on yet. I will be getting one soon though. Thanks for your help and I will mark your answer as correct (as Im sure it is) :)

Comment: Hi Mayo323, I finally got my iPhone with iOS 7.0.2 and the date&time returned from the date in the picker on my device is still showing as an hour behind in my NSLog. So I'm afraid I have had to un-mark yours as the answer.